# Spring data JPA logging

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to log the time taken by the JPA repository to save the data into the database.
Currently, I have used the Spring around Aspect to log it but it seems not so accurate because it doesn't commit until the end of @Transactional method.

```
@Timed(metricName = "inmtPersistence")
public void persistInmt(final List<T> inmtList) {

    if (inmtList.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    Map<String, E> inmtEntityMapFromDb = getInmtEntitiesFromDb(inmtList);

    List<E> inmtEntities = getInmtEntities(inmtList, inmtEntityMapFromDb);

    try {
        inmtRepository.saveAll(inmtEntities);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception ");
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) , which will log out execution time for all individual queries.